# How i trigger a lambda function every time I call a S3 static site

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, triggers

i have a lambda function that returns a json which is read by S3 static website, i need the lambda function to be triggered every time i access the static website, is there any way to do this? ("s3 is being accessed by a route53 record like CNAME")

- Lambda updated key bucket
- S3 static website Read bucket
- S3 is called with route53 CNAME
- **Lambda function need a trigger for uptade bucket**

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an [api gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) as a trigger for the lambda function. That way, every time a client accesses the website, the client can send a fetch request to the rest endpoint and the lambda would then return the json object that you are looking for. Let me know if that helps.